# Mongodb says i'm out of space, which I'm not. What could cause it?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, nosql

I have this huge 1mi documents collection; when inserting in it today, mongo rose a exception saying I was out of disk: failed: exception: Can't take a write lock while out of disk space

Checking on my hard drive, I still have 300gb of free space, so, basically, I have no idea why mongodb is telling me that I'm out of space. What could be causing this?

Comment: On ext3/4 there is an option to have some space reserved for root 5% by default - might be similar case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly are on a limited partition.

To see your partitions, you can use the command:

```
$ df
```

Answer (score 0):

So, here was the problem: my hard drive was partitioned. mongodb dbpath was pointing to my root partition, which is much smaller than my home partition. What I had to do was change /etc/mongodb.conf dbpath to another partition with space available.

Anyway, thanks Gnucki, you helped me big time! Would have never seen this problem without your help.

Comment: Glad if I could help you!